# mysql groupconcat [BLOB -5B] result

Tags: mysql, concatenation

```
SELECT model as model,colorpack.colorID as color
FROM bags LEFT OUTER JOIN colorpack on bagsID=colorpack.colorpack
WHERE colorpack.colorpack='62'
```

This select give me something like this:

```
model     | color
------------------
CoolModel |  26
CoolModel |  28
```

And i need this:

```
model     | color
------------------
CoolModel |  26,28
So i try to use GROUP_CONCAT:
    SELECT model as model,GROUP_CONCAT(colorpack.colorID) as color
    FROM bags LEFT OUTER JOIN colorpack on bagsID=colorpack.colorpack
    WHERE colorpack.colorpack='62'
```

But then i get:

```
model     | color
-------------------------
CoolModel |  [BLOB - 5 B]
After google/stackoverflow research i found that maybe max value is problem, but after:
    show variables like "%concat%";
Variable_name           | Value
--------------------------------
group_concat_max_len    | 1024
```

So i think it's not it, any other suggestion?

EDIT: 
Same code working if i select varchar, but when i select tinyint, it's not working.

Comment: Are you using phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes, from known host service

Comment: I think there's a thing that looks like this <-T->  Press it! :-)

Comment: Not sure then, but, FWIW, I'm yet to a concatenation problem can that couldn't best be solved in the application code.

Answer (score 0):

You tried `GROUP_CONCAT` but you did not use `GROUP BY` in your query that might be the problem, Try This:

```
SELECT model as model,GROUP_CONCAT(colorpack.colorID) as color
FROM bags LEFT OUTER JOIN colorpack on bagsID=colorpack.colorpack
WHERE colorpack.colorpack='62' GROUP BY model
```